# Setting a common zero on primary and secondary Y axes

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, axes

How do I get a secondary Y-axis to share a zero point with the primary Y-axis? I don't care about the rest of the intervals lining up or anything of that sort, I just want the primary and secondary Y-axes to share the same zero.

I'm aggregating data by week by default, but my chart can change to aggregate by day or month as well. As an example, when I aggregate by week, all values are positive on both axes, so the bottom of the chart sits at 0 (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8w30.jpg), but when I aggregate daily, I get some negative values on the primary axis. At that point, I still have all positive values on the secondary axis, so the bottom of the graph jumps down to -2000 on the primary axis and stays at 0 on the secondary (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAB1c.jpg).

I've tried setting the `Axis.Crossing` attribute on the axes, I've tried setting the minimums equal, I've tried a number of other things and nothing seems to work. Is there any way to use a common zero so that low positive values on the secondary axis don't look like they're negative as happens in the second image?

**Edit**: I'm using WinForms in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I am guessing you are using WinForms?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have specified that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the `Axes` to share their `Minimum` and also `Maximum` values by setting the `Axis.Minimum` and `Maximum` values, e.g. like this:

```
 ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
 CA.AxisY2.Maximum = CA.AxisY.Maximum;
 CA.AxisY2.Minimum = CA.AxisY.Minimum;
```

If you don't know how the values are spread you may want to calculate the common min and max values:

```
 ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

 double min = Math.Min(CA.AxisY.Minimum, CA.AxisY2.Minimum);
 double max = Math.Max(CA.AxisY.Maximum, CA.AxisY2.Maximum);

 CA.AxisY.Maximum = max;
 CA.AxisY2.Maximum = max;
 CA.AxisY.Minimum = min;
 CA.AxisY2.Minimum = min;
```

Note that this will change the display for the `Points` in one or both `Series`..:

[image][image]

Also note that whichever way you change those values, the Axes will have to display the truth about the values; so if the two Series display values in different scales you will have to find a way to calculate the min&max values so that they share a common zero.

If e.g. you know that the 2nd `Series` values are `x` times larger you could set its min/max values to `x` times of those from `Series1`..:

```
 CA.AxisY.Maximum = 15 * CA.AxisY2.Maximum;
 CA.AxisY.Minimum = 15 * CA.AxisY2.Minimum;
```

This is a rather simple way, but it works (using different data point values):

[image][image]

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks, that was very informative!

Comment: For some reason, even setting the minimum on the secondary axis to (in this case) -327 still displays the bottom of the axis as 0. Changing the maximum works fine, but the minimum never displays anything below 0.

Comment: Hm, that shouldn't be. Shot in the dark: There is a [`IsStartedFromZero`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.isstartedfromzero%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for the Axis. You don't happen to have it set? Can you link to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing both of the axis to have same **proportions**, just need to decide which axis proportion to use.
In this example I'm using the primary axis proportions:

```
 private static void ForceCommonZero(Chart chart)
    {
        chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
        Axis y1 = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
        Axis y2 = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2;
        double proportion = y1.Maximum / (-y1.Minimum);
        y2.Maximum = proportion * (-y2.Minimum);
    }
```

Please note that I'm assuming both of the axis are zero crossed (Maximum > 0 && Minimum < 0), this need to be checked (and then this can be implemented as an extension method)